# How would you close a jpanel?

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    // ask player for his username, this is used for login.
    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = rand.nextInt(1000 - 1) + 1;

    Object[] options1 = {"Login", "Random Username",
            "Quit"};

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JLabel("Enter your desired username:"));
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(16);
    panel.add(textField);

    //random usernames
    String words = "username:noob:player:slayer:foreveruser:forevernoob:foreverplayer:lol:wrectlikeaboos:darkalien:gold_in_silver:zeebra:zebra:maddox:canada:canadian:richtard";
    String[] wordsAsArray = words.split(":");
    int index = new Random().nextInt(wordsAsArray.length);
    String randomWord = wordsAsArray[index];
    Random num = new Random();
    int numr = num.nextInt(1000 - 1) + 1;

    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Forever: Login",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options1, null);
    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as " + textField.getText());
    }
    //randomusername = no
    //quit = cancel
    if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.exit(1)
    }
    if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as " + randomWord + numr);
    }
    //String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your username: ", "User"+r);
    Login client = new Login("hi");
}

public Login(String userName) throws MalformedURLException {
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
    launcher.init();
    this.username = userName;
}
```

Basically, when you run the program, you get a popup asking for your username. If you press quit, it runs the game anyway without any username (not supposed to happen) and if you press   X it does too. How would I make it so it just ends the program instead of it running without any username.

Thank you.

Comment: Use an if-else statement...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Where should I use that?

Answer (score 1):

Where you handle the action of pressing quit, you could call [`System.exit(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-) (assuming you have nothing to clean up or save off that isn't being done in a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-)).

Comment: I tried doing a event like that, but it only works if it's a jframe, which it's not. No idea why it's like that :/ (it's from "Jeu", a open source 2d rpg java game). I'll add that to the Quit button though

Comment: @user3930774 why not just add your panel to a jframe?

Comment: @MichaelParker How would I do that...? My idea is to do something like this: http://iamumbreon.tk/images/570500d30543132a547b.png for a launcher. Instead of selecting a resolution, it has a simple field for a username and there would be the 3 buttons like above (random username, cancel, login) and pressing X would close the game (I don't know how to do)

Comment: @user3930774 A bit confused, what is the current issue right now for you now that you have the System.exit(int) in place? You want to have the program end when they press no? You would have to if so, add a System.exit(int) in that `if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)` if.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand what the `JOptionPane` is telling you...

From the [JavaDocs for `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Component, Object, String, int, int, Icon, Object[], Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))

> Returns:
>   an integer indicating the option chosen by the user, or CLOSED_OPTION if the user closed the dialog

This can be a little vaguge, but, essentially what this will do is return in the index of the `Object[]` options which the user selected.  This means that the normal constents won't have any meaning (other then `CLOSED_OPTION`).

So instead of using `NO_OPTION` or `CANCEL_OPTION`, you need to use `0` for `Login`, `1` for `Random Username` and `2` for `Quit`, for example...

```
if (result != 2 && result != JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
    if (result == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as " + textField.getText());
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as " + randomWord + numr);
    }
    //String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your username: ", "User"+r);
    Login client = new Login("hi");    
}
```

Then you should also only create your `Login` if a valid response is chosen.

I'm old school, I believe in one entry point and one exit point for the program, littering your code with `System.exit`s will only make it more difficult to debug in the future - IMHO

Comment: Alright, I did that, I made a public string called username, and then in the class where it labels players, it sets it as the username string. http://pastebin.com/dv2Nqnf0

Comment: +1 nice code example. And about entry and exit points you're right, it becomes harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for one more possible result: `JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION`. That is for when the user hits the X or closes it any other way.

In the question, you said it also didn't work right for the CANCEL_OPTION, but I see you edited you question and fixed that (you added the `System.exit(1)`)

Also, I would recommend writing it with an if/else statement so you only need to worry about the actions you care about:

```
String username;
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    username = textField.getText();
} else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    username = randomWord + numr;
} else { //Or add if's for CANCEL and CLOSED if you want to do something else
    System.exit(0);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as " + username);
Login client = new Login(username);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I did something similar. Here's my final product: http://pastebin.com/gdmEd8Pb
(I had no idea CLOSED_OPTION existed)